# Possible Proof that determinant of submatrix of Unitary matrix is alswys greater 0?

Tags: matrices, determinant, orthogonal-matrices

Is there a method to show that $\det(R) > 0$ with $R^{M\times M}$ as a submatrix of an  orthogonal matrix $Q^{N\times N}$, with $QQ^T=I_N$, $M<N$.

I would be grateful for a helpful hint.

Comment: So you want to show in particular that every entry is positive? Did you try $N=2$? A rotation by 60 degrees?

Comment: What about $-I$ for even $N$?